# GHC/Haskell profiling: function consumes time without being called

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I have compiled a Haskell program with GHC with enabled profiling.

$ ./server +RTS -M6m -p -RTS

I get a profile like:

```
                                                   individual    inherited
COST CENTRE      MODULE           no.    entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

poke_a4u64       Generator      2859       56436   0.0    0.0     0.4    0.4
 storeParameter  Generator      2860           0   0.4    0.4     0.4    0.4
  ppCurrent      Generator      2866       56436   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  ppFeedback     Generator      2861       56436   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

It looks like storeParameter is never called, but consumes time and memory. Since storeParameter calls ppCurrent, I guess that storeParameter is called 56436 times, like ppCurrent. Why is not shown?

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the code you are profiling, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in the ghc profiling. I don't know of a workaround, but Simon M has promised improvements in the next release.

Comment: Do you have a link to the GHC Trac ticket?

Comment: I can't remember if there's a Trac ticket, but I've talked to Simon M about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the `entries` column to lie in my own code: e.g. `main` getting called **6 times**!

So I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: `entries` is not the number of times a function is called.  It's the number of times a call graph node has been entered.  The two are not the same.

Comment: @JohnL: still, why would `main`'s call graph node be entered more than once?  No recursion or anything: just doing a straight "read parameters in from command line, print some stuff to stdout, evaluate a pure function and save results of it to disk".

Comment: it's speculation on my part, but maybe returning to `main` from a system call counts?  It would be nice if the documentation were a bit more thorough.